# how void operator exactly works in javascript

Tags: javascript

As a **definition** said The **void** operator evaluates the given expression and then returns **undefined**.

so in this code

```
void function test() {
  console.log('test function executed');
};
```

if we call it like **test()** , then should `console.log('test function executed');` evaluated first then after finishing return `undefined` ? , rather than returning `undefined` only ? like this one

```
void function iife() {
  console.log('iife is executed');
}();
```

Comment: It does evaluate that first.

Comment: Evaluated doesn't mean that the function itself is run, the second function only runs because of the `()` after the function declaration (Often called something like a "self invoking function")

Comment: @technophyle can you explain it more ?

Comment: @DBS so what I should consider when saying evaluating something ? , in second answer , why it runs it rather than evaluating it and returns undefined

Comment: In the second example it works because `()` has higher precedence than `void`, meaning that `()` will be evaluated first (calling the function), then `void`.

Comment: To not need void, for example in a bookmarklet, you can just do 
`(function iife() { console.log('iife is executed'); })();`

Comment: Any operator will work really `!function iife() { console.log('iife is executed'); }()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `void` operator evaluates the expression that follows it, and then returns `undefined`.

In the case of `test()` function, as I said, it *does* evaluate the expression, which is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```
void function test() {
  console.log('test function executed');
};
```

So, you ask, why isn't the body executed? Because function expressions do *not* run the body. They just create the function somewhere in memory. The body is only run when the function is actually *called*.

Now, you call the function with `test()` and it throws:

> Error: test is not defined

Why? Because the name of the function expression's scope is limited to the function body, not outer scope, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#named_function_expression).

From the referenced article:

> If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression. **This name is then local only to the function body (scope)**.

In a nutshell, using `void` like above is kind of useless. It's just there for demonstration purpose and understanding how it works.

Comment: thanks a lot , one thing that i not figure out a while that is a function expression not a function declaration like a java .

Comment: yeah , your answer is the best ever , but  upvote them for they efforts .

Answer (score 3):

If we go over to this [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table), we see that function calls `()` have a precedence of 17, while the `void` operator only has a precedence of of 14 (same as `typeof`, `delete`, and `await`). Because of this, the following code

```
void function iife() {
  console.log('iife is executed');
}();
```

is actually treated like

```
void (function iife() {
  console.log('iife is executed');
}());
```

If you want the code to error then you need to use parentheses:

```js
// Cannot call 'undefined' as a function
(void function iife() {
  console.log('iife is executed');
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

These are two different expressions:

- one creates a function
- the other one calls the function

You can see that `void` works correctly with creating a function here:

```js
const x = function test() {
  console.log('test function executed');
};

console.log(x) // function
```

With void:

```js
const x = void function test() {
  console.log('test function executed');
};

console.log(x) // undefined
```

If you want the function call to return `undefined`, you have to use `void` when calling the function

```js
function test() {
  return 10
}

const x = void test()

console.log(x)
```